# Why is ConsoleTraceListener not writing to a Console?

Tags: .net

Quite often, I run into items in the .NET Framework that have little or no code examples on how to use the features. On other occasions, there are plenty of examples, but none of them seem to work as prescribed.

Case in point: The System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener class.

From everything I've read and every code example I've seen, when I'm doing something like the following:

```cs
ConsoleTraceListner listener = new ConsoleTraceListener();
listener.WriteLine("Yo");
```

...I should see a console window pop up with "Yo". However, instead of that expected output, it's writing "Yo" to the Visual Studio Output where one would see normal Trace/Debug messages.

I've attempted every iteration of examples I've Googled for, including config file setup of the appropriate listener, adding the listener to the Trace.Listeners collection, custom ConsoleTraceListener types, etc. I've even just compiled to a Release version and ran the executable (which does absolutely nothing).

What the heck am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Answering your comment to Orion Adrian's answer...

The point of a `ConsoleTraceListenter` or *any* `TraceListener` isn't to call it directly - it's to add it to the trace listener collection so that the rest of your code just has to call `Trace.Write` etc. For instance:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ConsoleTraceListener listener = new ConsoleTraceListener();
        Trace.Listeners.Add(listener);

        DoSomething();

        Trace.Flush();
    }

    static void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }

    static void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        // We don't want to have to pass all our logging
        // baggage down this far
        Trace.WriteLine("In DoSomethingElse");
    }
}
```

Compile that with TRACE defined, and you've got simple logging to the console. Personally I prefer logging with a bit more "oomph" such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html), but tracing is a good start.

Comment: Also in the case above you could have multiple Trace listeners, one for ConsoleTraceListener and maybe one for EventLogTraceListener.

Comment: @Jon, thanx much for your input. But I've written what you wrote almost verbatim. My comment states it above: "I've attempted every itteration of examples I've Googled for including...adding the listener to the Trace.Listeners collection...". But it still doesn't work the way I'm expecting it to. I've yet to stumble upon the right combination to actually render a console with text in it.

Comment: @Boydski: I was only answering your comment to Orion as to the benefits of using a trace listener in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Even with `TRACE` defined as suggested above, the console trace information will only be visible if the executable was created with `/target:exe`, i. e. as console executable. If it was created with `/target:winexe`, no console will be available, hence no trace output from a `ConsoleTraceListener`.

Comment: This is the only right answer. The ConsoleTraceListener should still write to the standard output, but it will not open a console window for you. If you can't change your application to a console application, there are some Win32 API functions you can use, e.g. `AllocConsole`, to make a console window appear.